# SQL to exclude NULL or value 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have below SQL code,

```
SELECT s.[CusNo] Supp, 
    RTRIM(CAST(s.[Customer] AS VARCHAR(50))) AS Name,
    s.[ConNo] Con, 
    RTRIM(CAST(s.[ConN] AS VARCHAR(50))) AS ConN,       
    sum(case when s.Date between convert(date,dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) - 1) and convert(date,dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) + 5) 
             then s.SELL else 0 end) ActualSales
FROM [dbo].[Reports] s
WHERE s.BOX = 2
AND   s.SELL <> 0
GROUP BY s.[CusNo], s.[Customer], s.ConNo, s.ConN
```

When I execute the above query, I am getting all the values (including 0 values) in ActualSales column.

How to remove the rows which as value 0 please?

Answer (score 2):

Use `having` clause

```
SELECT s.[CusNo] Supp, 
RTRIM(CAST(s.[Customer] AS VARCHAR(50)) ) AS Name,
s.[ConNo] Con, 
RTRIM(CAST(s.[ConN] AS VARCHAR(50)) ) AS ConN,
sum(case when s.Date between convert(date,dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) - 1) and convert(date,dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) + 5) 
           then s.SELL else 0 end) ActualSales

FROM [dbo].[Reports] s
WHERE s.BOX = 2 and s.SELL <> 0
GROUP BY s.[CusNo], s.[Customer], s.ConNo, s.ConN
having sum(case when s.Date between convert(date,dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) - 1) and convert(date,dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) + 5) 
           then s.SELL else 0 end)<>0
```

OR you can use subquery

```
select * from
(
    SELECT s.[CusNo] Supp, 
    RTRIM(CAST(s.[Customer] AS VARCHAR(50)) ) AS Name,
     s.[ConNo] Con, 
    RTRIM(CAST(s.[ConN] AS VARCHAR(50)) ) AS ConN,
    sum(case when s.Date between convert(date,dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) - 1) and convert(date,dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) + 5) 
           then s.SELL else 0 end) ActualSales

FROM [dbo].[Reports] s
WHERE s.BOX = 2 and s.SELL <> 0
GROUP BY s.[CusNo], s.[Customer], s.ConNo, s.ConN
)A where ActualSales<>0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might get what you want by moving the `case` condition to the `where` clause:

```
SELECT s.[CusNo] as Supp, 
       RTRIM(CAST(s.[Customer] AS VARCHAR(50)) ) AS Name,
       s.[ConNo] as Con, 
       RTRIM(CAST(s.[ConN] AS VARCHAR(50)) ) AS ConN,
       SUM(s.SELL) as ActualSales
FROM [dbo].[Reports] s
WHERE s.BOX = 2 AND s.SELL <> 0 AND
      s.Date BETWEEN convert(date, dateadd(wk, datediff(week, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) - 1) and
                     convert(date,dateadd(wk, datediff(week, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) + 5)
GROUP BY s.[CusNo], s.[Customer], s.ConNo, s.ConN;
```

It is possibly that `ActualSales` could still be `0` (if `Sales` could be negative.  In that case, you would want a `HAVING` clause:  `HAVING SUM(Sales) <> 0`.

Because this approach filters before aggregation, it might also benefit performance.